# find if string contains mutliple words in r

Tags: r, string

I have the following data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(Name = c("John", "Company A pty Ltd", ""), Surname = c("Smith", "", "Company B"), Company = c("Company D", "A Ltd", "Company B"))
```

I want to check if the Company column contains any word that is either in the firstName or the Surname.

I have used the following code:

```
dat$clinicOnly <- mapply(grepl, pattern=dat$firstName, dat$Company)
```

But what it checks is the whole string is present. Hence it works for the first row, but misses the second row, and gets the last row correct because it detected a blank firstName entry.

How to write a function that produces FALSE, TRUE, TRUE ?

Comment: Don't have time for a long answer but try: `apply(dat, 1, function(x){grepl(paste(x[1:2], collapse="|"), x[3])})`

Comment: Works very well, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, using `intersect` to do the hard work?:

```
v1 <- strsplit(do.call(paste, dat[1:2]), "\\s+")
v2 <- strsplit(as.character(dat$Company), "\\s+")

mapply(function(x,y) length(intersect(x,y)) > 1, v1, v2)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Also answers the question, just with more lines of code.